# How to hide all XAML file and cs file in program file folder when compiling exe in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, hide

I create a WPF application and create an `.exe` in Visual Studio.

When I install it, I find out that I can see all XAML and `.cs` files in the program files folder. How can I prevent people from viewing the source code?

[program folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caAMh.png)

Comment: That's not a typical output. The bin/Debug or bin/Release folder shouldn't contain .cs files unless you copied them yourself.

Comment: Could be that the Build Action of those files is wrong, for me it's 'C# compiler' for the .xaml.cs files.

Comment: Thank you Felix and Rob, I finally find out why the cs files appear in the program folder.I don't know why the there is a "source files from xxxProject(Active)" in the Project SetUp, so it copies all my source code to exe.I delete the node and everything is on the right track.